# Memory leak related issue with Threadlocals in elasticsearch

Tags: tomcat, elasticsearch

I have a web service, where every time a button is pressed from UI, it connects to elastic search and fires a query. This is the code which is executed every time. The issue is that after a while, intermittently, the UI hangs.

```
private static final String CONFIG_CLUSTER_NAME = "cluster.name";

private static final String CLUSTER_NAME = "sample_es";
private static final String[] transportAddress = {
    //Machine details
};

private static final int transportPort = 9300;

public static Client initClient(){
    settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put(CONFIG_CLUSTER_NAME, CLUSTER_NAME).build();

        Client client = new TransportClient(settings);
        for (int i=0 ; i < transportAddress.length-1 ; i++){
            ((TransportClient)client).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(transportAddress[i], transportPort));
        }
        logger.info("TransportClient Created"); 
        return client;  
}


public static int query( String query) throws Exception
{
    Client client = null;
    try{

            client = initClient();

            //Query search code

    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(client != null){
            client.close();
            logger.info("TransportClient Closed");
        }
    }
        return result_count;
}
```

Whenever we restart the tomcat server, this is the error message we are seeing in logs. How should we fix this?

```
[org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (value
[org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y.ThreadLocalRandom$1@5838ce3e]) and a value of type
[org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y.ThreadLocalRandom] (value 
[org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y.ThreadLocalRandom@796c75b1]) but failed to remove it
when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unlikely to be a real issue and more of an issue that Elasticsearch is not using threadpools managed by Tomcat. So whenever you restart Tomcat close to after a query has been run, then it most likely *thinks* it sees a memory leak. This is common for "unmanaged" threads to trigger in Tomcat. With that said, you can verify that is or is not cleaning up after itself via running a profiler, then monitoring threads and resources. If is not cleaning up properly, then I suggest creating an issue on Elasticsearch's GitHub repository.

With respect to what you're doing with the client creation: I definitely suggest that you *not* create, use, then throw away the client. Allocate it on start, then reuse the client rather than constantly recreating it on demand. Then add a shutdown hook to close it when Tomcat wants to stop. Also, `for (int i=0 ; i < transportAddress.length-1 ; i++)` is skipping the last transport address; use `i < transportAddress.length` without the `-1`.

Unrelated, but all Elasticsearch `Client`s implement `AutoCloseable` (added in Java 7), which means you could simplify your code to autoclose it *if you wanted to keep doing that*:

```
try (Client client = initClient()) {
    // Query search code
}
catch (Exception e) {
    logger.warning("An unexpected error occurred for the query: {}",
                   query, e);
}
```

Comment: is it happening because we are creating and closing a new client for every query??

[https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/283](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/283)

Will having only one connection forever solve this? Does ES connection stay live even if no one uses it for a couple hours? Or it becomes stale?

That is why I am creating and closing everytime.

Comment: It should be fine to keep the client open.